# How to aggregate column in One SQL without using the inner query in SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server, aggregate-functions, sql-server-2014

I have data set some thing like this :

```
nbr  | date         | nbr2  | order_qty      | recived_qty
1234 | 8/14/2016    | 12    | 123            | 16
1234 | 8/14/2016    | 12    | 123            | 44
1234 | 8/14/2016    | 12    | 123            | 29
1234 | 8/14/2016    | 12    | 123            | 34
1234 | 8/14/2016    | 13    | 44             | 0
```

based on first three column i need to add the order qty only once otherwise it will duplicated. I have the below SQL that does the work, but i need it to be done in one SQL only(no inner SQL ).

Is there is way we can do this in one SQL in SQL server 2014 databse ?

```
SELECT Sum(A.total_ord) AS total_ord, 
       Sum(A.total_rec) AS total_rec 
 FROM (
    SELECT nbr, 
           date, 
           nbr2, 
           order_qty AS total_ord, 
           Sum(recived_qty) AS total_rec 
    FROM table 
    GROUP BY nbr, 
             date, 
             nbr2, 
             order_qty
        ) AS A
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Is there a specific constraint the prevents you from using a derived table as you have displayed above?

Comment: But it seems in final output you should get only sum of all rows and inner grouping will not have any speciality then.

Comment: Well seems that the values in the order_qty field are repeated and they do not want to double count them when summing which is why the derived table to group by that field is there.

Comment: Your requirements are strange since order_qty hardly seems fit to be used as a indentifier (what if there are two orders with the same qty?). Also (for what you asked) you can just fetch order_qty, no need to aggregate twice. In general you can achiev what you asked for using a self join. finally  16+44+29+34 =123 are you looking for a way to check if all you ordered was already received?

Answer (score 2):

Are you looking something like this?

```
select sum(distinct order_qty) as total_ord, sum(received_qty) as total_rec from #temp
```

Values in the table:

```
insert into #temp (nbr,date, nbr2, order_qty, received_qty) values
 (1234 , '8/14/2016',     12    , 123            , 16 )
,(1234 , '8/14/2016',     12    , 123            , 44 )
,(1234 , '8/14/2016',     12    , 123            , 29 )
,(1234 , '8/14/2016',     12    , 123            , 34 )
,(1234 , '8/14/2016',     13    , 44             , 0  )
```

Comment: +1 because that seems like what the user is asking. However, if you had 123 as an order_qty on a different day, the query would fail to pick it up

Comment: I think it should be sum( order_qty) as total_ord